# Active Setup StubPath key not being added

Tags: registry

My current setup is as follows:

Registy key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\10Harmon.ie** contains the REG_SZ strings *Version* with a value of *1* and *StubPath* with a value of *reg add HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\common\open find\adminaddedplaces\place0 /v "name" /d "harmon.ie favorites" /f*

When I login the **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\10Harmon.ie** key is there with the REG_SZ string *Version* with a value of *1*

However the **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\common\open find\adminaddedplaces\place0** has not been created as I would have expected

I've tried a few variants. Using the full **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** instead of **HKCU** and using quotes around the registry key location, but I have yet to make any progress.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Insufficient privileges.

If you check permissions for registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies`, you should find that the typical user is limited to the **Read** privilege and the local System account and accounts with membership in the local Administrator's group enjoy full privileges.

All child objects will inherit these permissions and so, when Active Setup runs in the logged-on user's context, the **reg.exe** command fails because the user only has **Read** access.

*<sup>I realize this is a wee bit old but I thought I'd pitch in for those who might stumble across this question.</sup>*